# Escaping file name when uploading with Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http

Tags: php, zend-framework

Is there the functionality to escape the filename before uploading with [`Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.file.html#zend.file.transfer.introduction).

For example file names such as '`tes file$"f.gif`' will cause problems.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

check out "Zend_Filter_File_Rename" i think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.file.transfer.filters.html#zend.file.transfer.filters.rename